# How to show tooltip on MS Chart

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, mschart

I am using MS Chart control to draw graphs on Winform.

I want to show the current (x,y)  Value as tooltip on Mousedown on chartarea.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the chart samples ([Samples Environments for Microsoft Chart Controls](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591))

```
// Set ToolTips for Data Point Series
chart1.Series[0].ToolTip = "Percent: #PERCENT";

// Set ToolTips for legend items
chart1.Series[0].LegendToolTip = "Income in #LABEL  is #VAL million";

// Set ToolTips for the Data Point labels
chart1.Series[0].LabelToolTip = "#PERCENT";

// Set ToolTips for second Data Point
chart1.Series[0].Points[1].ToolTip = "Unknown";
```

Comment: That works.... additionally I wanted to get value when user does mousdown anywhere in the chartarea ,I could do it through this statement..                                                          val=Convert.ToInt32(chart1.ChartAreas["chartAreaFlows"].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X));

Comment: This supplied link is broken.  Maybe this is similar and helpful https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591

Answer (score 7):

If you want to show tooltips with maximum and minimum values in Range type charts, the following code can be used.

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = "Min:#VALY1, Max:#VALY2";
```

Answer (score 6):

This tooltip will appear on mouseover. I'm not sure if you can set it for mousedown event.

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = "#VALY, #VALX";
```