# Getting x-coordinate on Chart from mouse click

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, charts, mschart

I have a chart on a Windows Form with several line graphs.  I would like to be able to get the x-coordinate from a mouse click on the chart in such a way that the user would be able to place vertical annotations on the chart at the location of the click.  I looked at the Chart.HitTest function, but that will only do what I need if the user clicks on a data point, not anywhere in the chart area.  Is there a way to do this easily?

Answers in C# or VB welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647666/finding-the-value-of-the-points-in-a-chart Did u check this ?

Comment: I had not found that one, although I had searched a couple pages of stackoverflow before posting.  That looks like exactly what I need.  I'll post it as the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Quantbuff pointed out, this has been answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647666/finding-the-value-of-the-points-in-a-chart).

Essentially, you must handle the click event (e) on the chart and call `Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X)` and `Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y)` to get the values.