# see values of chart points when the mouse is on points

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I have a chart and I want the user to see the values when the pointer is on the points.
By using digEmAll's help in the page [finding the value of the points in a chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647666/finding-the-value-of-the-points-in-a-chart) ,I could write the following code:

```
Point? prevPosition = null; 
ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();  

void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{     
    var pos = e.Location;     
    if (prevPosition.HasValue && pos == prevPosition.Value)         
        return;     
    tooltip.RemoveAll();     
    prevPosition = pos;     
    var results = chart1.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y, false, ChartElementType.PlottingArea);     
    foreach (var result in results)     
    {         
        if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.PlottingArea)         
        {            
            chart1.Series[0].ToolTip = "X=#VALX, Y=#VALY";          
        }    
    } 
}
```

by the above code,the user can see the values when the pointer is **near to** a series.But now How can I let the user to see the values only when the pointer is **on** the points?
I replaced

```
int k = result.PointIndex;
if (k >= 0)
{
    chart1.Series[0].Points[k].ToolTip = "X=#VALX, Y=#VALY";
}
```

instead of

```
chart1.Series[0].ToolTip = "X=#VALX, Y=#VALY";
```

to solve my problem.But It wasn't usefull.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should modify the code in this way:

```
Point? prevPosition = null;
ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();

void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var pos = e.Location;
    if (prevPosition.HasValue && pos == prevPosition.Value)
        return;
    tooltip.RemoveAll();
    prevPosition = pos;
    var results = chart1.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y, false,
                                    ChartElementType.DataPoint);
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
        {
            var prop = result.Object as DataPoint;
            if (prop != null)
            {
                var pointXPixel = result.ChartArea.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(prop.XValue);
                var pointYPixel = result.ChartArea.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(prop.YValues[0]);

                // check if the cursor is really close to the point (2 pixels around the point)
                if (Math.Abs(pos.X - pointXPixel) < 2 &&
                    Math.Abs(pos.Y - pointYPixel) < 2)
                {
                    tooltip.Show("X=" + prop.XValue + ", Y=" + prop.YValues[0], this.chart1,
                                    pos.X, pos.Y - 15);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to check if the mouse is very close to the point e.g. `2` pixels around it  (because is really unlikely to be **exactly** on the point) and show the tooltip in that case.

[Here's a complete working example.](http://pastebin.com/PzhHtfMu)

Comment: Working perfectly for primary axis. But the condition `(Math.Abs(pos.X - pointXPixel) < 2 && Math.Abs(pos.Y - pointYPixel) < 2)` fails for secondary axis series.

Comment: @RameshDurai: yes correct, this code considers only the primary axis.

Comment: This code worked for me! However, I would like to know how to gain access to the event where the mouse has moved away from the datapoint (i.e. so I can change the datapoint color from COLOR_HOVERED to COLOR_NORMAL)...

Comment: @Shn_Android_Dev : why don't you just set the hovered color in the if statement where there's the tooltip and in the "else" (meaning: the cursor is outside the point) part of the if statement you reset to normal ?

Answer (score 9):

I would take this solution:

Add custom tooltip event handler:

```
 this.chart1.GetToolTipText += this.chart1_GetToolTipText;
```

Implement event handler:

```
  private void chart1_GetToolTipText(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
  {
     // Check selected chart element and set tooltip text for it
     switch (e.HitTestResult.ChartElementType)
     {
        case ChartElementType.DataPoint:
           var dataPoint = e.HitTestResult.Series.Points[e.HitTestResult.PointIndex];
           e.Text = string.Format("X:\t{0}\nY:\t{1}", dataPoint.XValue, dataPoint.YValues[0]);
           break;
     }
  }
```

Comment: I have tried your code.It fires when my mouse is hover the chart but no tooltip has shown.

Comment: @M_Mogharrabi: I cannot test it yet, but from my memory:
- You have to show the "point markers"
- Do not set the ToolTip property of the data point, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256283/show-tooltip-only-on-the-datapoint-for-line-graph-in-mschart

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following as a possible better option than tooltips...use the label feature of the chart control.

```
DataPoint _prevPoint;
void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // this if statement clears the values from the previously activated point.
    if (_prevPoint) {
        _prevPoint.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None;
        _prevPoint.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
    }

    var result = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y, ChartElementType.DataPoint);
    if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
    {
        var prop = result.Object as DataPoint;
        if (prop != null)
        {
            prop.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            prop.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Star4;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested this and i'm using it currently.  It's very nice on charts with a lot of points since it shows the marker on the chart as well.

Comment: Thanks, this is working. But I think there is one line missing after creating the marker `_prevPoint = prop` to store a reference of the previous marker. There are some typos in your code. I'll fix them.

Comment: It runs and the prop != null fires when I mouse over a data point, but I don't see a marker.  Is that something that's supposed to popup?