# viewing more details about points on a 2D chart

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, charts

I have a program with a two dimensional point chart of two series. Each point on the chart represents a member of a list composed of instances of a class which has several properties. I mapped two of the properties as X and Y coordinates for my chart.

```
if (stackerCrane.Missions[i].MissionErroneous == true)
{
    graphs[SCNo - 1].chart1.Series["Unsuccessful"].Points.AddXY(
                                         stackerCrane.Missions[i].XCoord, 
                                         stackerCrane.Missions[i].YCoord);
}
else
{
    graphs[SCNo - 1].chart1.Series["Successful"].Points.AddXY(
                                         stackerCrane.Missions[i].XCoord, 
                                         stackerCrane.Missions[i].YCoord);
}
```

If needed, I would like to be able to see the value of another property of the class by clicking or hovering the pointer on the points. Are there any ways that can help me with this issue? 
I would appreciate your help and opinion on this matter. [Here is a view of the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9rt7.jpg)

Comment: You can add a Tooltip to each Point: `int pi = graphs[SCNo - 1].chart1.Series["Unsuccessful"].Points.AddXY(stackerCrane.Missions[i].XCoord, stackerCrane.Missions[i].YCoord); yourseries.Points[pi].Tooltip = "sadsdsdasd\r" + yourpoint.XValue + asdsadas..`

Comment: Thank you for your reply @TaW.
Yes,tooltips worked fine. I will publish the result as an answer to my question soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is called tooltip.
There are many other discussions about tooltips and the details about it.
I have visited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648828/see-values-of-chart-points-when-the-mouse-is-on-points/) and the accepted answer to it from [digEmAll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/316644/digemall/) was a great help for me.