# Can I select points in a polar chart in MSChart?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, mschart

I would like to select points in a Polar chart in MSChart.
I have the `ChartAreas.CursorX(and Y).IsUserSelection = true`. But when I try to select a zone, the `SelectionChanged` event does not activate, nor do I see a selection in the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, looking at the inner code of mschart, the cursors user selection is inhibited when the chart area is circular (as in the polar chart).

In fact the decompiled code of `chart.MouseDown` is something like this:

```
if(!area.IsCircular ...)
{
   area.CursorX.Cursor_MouseDown(this, e);
   area.CursorY.Cursor_MouseDown(this, e);
}
```

So, the only way is to handle the `MouseClick`/`MouseMove` events, get the points values using `HitTest` method and do whatever you need manually.

For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9647958/316644) explains how to show a tooltip on `MouseClick`/`MouseMove` event.

---

**EDIT :**

[Here's a full working code piece](http://pastebin.com/cmd2j6ia) showing how to implement the selection in a polar chart.

Screen-shot:

[image]

Comment: What about a drawing method? Can I draw a circle or rectangle and get all the points inside the figure?

Comment: Where should I start if I want to develop this option?

Comment: @user1685358: I have created a full example (and it has been really difficult...). Check my edit :)

Comment: Sorry, the code on paste-bin was set as private. Now it's accessible :)

Comment: thanks :) I just checked the page again since last time... thank you very much