# Hover over point on Point Chart in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, charts, hover

I'm creating a website with ASP.NET and i'm using the stock Chart control to map some data points onto a scatter plot.  What I would like is to have the ability to hover over a point and reveal a small usercontrol with some information about that datapoint.  Is this possible or should I look outside of the MS Controls for a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably looking for something like a tool-tip feature from Microsoft chart.

take a look at this

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2008/11/11/microsoft-chart-control-how-to-using-keywords.aspx

[How to show tooltip on MS Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136072/how-to-show-tooltip-on-ms-chart)